# How do I run standalone ruby or python file from nginx?

Tags: python, ruby, nginx

I have a ruby file `index.rb` that contains `puts "this is to show in nginx landing page"`.

My nginx landing location is `/usr/share/nginx/html` and my configuration is

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.rb index.html index.htm;
        server_name localhost;
       }
```

How do I print those lines without ruby on rails or python django? Do I need to build my code?

Comment: You want a static page, then? Just make an `.html` file.

Comment: its not about static page. But i need to run standalone ruby or python without framework. and by default nginx is having index.html running as static page and I know that @tadman.

Comment: I'm wondering why you need to do this? At the bare minimum with Ruby you want to be writing a [Rack compliant program](http://rack.github.io) like [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com).

Comment: why cant you use a cronjob to run a standalone script?

Comment: I just want to know whether **nginx can run it or not**. And i know `Sinatra` and `cron`. @Trying2Learn , @tadman

Comment: ok. Have you taken a look at CGI scripts. https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/CGI.html

Comment: If you're really, stubbornly determined to do this, [Nginx supports CGI](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/simplecgi/). I'd strongly advise against it, the performance is usually brutal. Even [Python recommends alternatives](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html) like FastCGI and WSGI.

Comment: I totally understood and agree what you are saying @tadman but my business logic requires it and i need to do some R&D on it. so i just want to know whether nginx can run index.rb or index.py just like indec.html or index.php. And your help here would be great

Comment: nginx does NOT RUN index.html, it serves it.

Comment: If you could better articulate your requirements I could try and help you come up with a more optimal solution here. I've linked to the Nginx CGI documentation if you want to try that approach. `index.php` requires the PHP module, obviously, as PHP doesn't run in CGI mode.

Answer (score 2):

Nginx **cannot** run the `index.rb` script, in part because it does not have an embedded ruby (or python) interpreter. What you might want to do is to run your script through a uWSGI app. As documented [here](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/RackQuickstart.html), for ruby, you need to create an `app.ru` script with a `call` entry point (which will just load your `index.rb` script). It is then run via:

```
uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:3031 --rack app.ru
```

Your nginx server can then access the uWSGI process with the following configuration:

```
location / {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3031;
    uwsgi_modifier1 7;
}
```

Comment: +1 for `Nginx cannot run the index.rb script, in part because it does not have an embedded ruby (or python) interpreter` and the link for uWSGI @Regis B.

Comment: What solution did you eventually find?